# Pass a value from an input for pagination in React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Im trying to make a very easy pagination function on a react 16 project, my thought is just to pass the buttons value to the api query to get the "&page=" number and navigate to second page, third and so on.
Im using unsplash api for consuming pictures. I think a "prev, next" button should be enough but I cant find a good way to do it wothout making lot of changes.

I tryied some solutions I found here. but none of them apply to my simple idea.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import ItemList from './components/ItemList';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import SearchImg from './components/SearchImg';
import Pagination from './components/Pagination';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imgs: [],
      loadingState: true
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.performSearch();
}

performSearch = (query = 'guitar') => {
var pagi = [1]; // here is the variable I should pass the values to.


var headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
axios({
method: 'GET',
url: 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page='+(pagi)+'&per_page=20&query='+(query), 

//(pagi) is where I want to pass the values


headers: headers,
}).then(data => {
this.setState({ imgs: data.data.results, loadingState: false });
})
.catch(err => {
console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
});

};

render() {
  return (
  <div className="container">
  <Navigation /> // This is just a hardcode html buttons navigation.

//maybe just adding two buttons, one for prev, one for next should be enough?.

  <div>
  <SearchImg onSearch={this.performSearch} />
  </div>
  {this.state.loadingState
  ? <p style={centrar}>Loading...</p>

  : <ItemList data={this.state.imgs} />}
    <Footer />
  </div>

  );
}
}
```

Comment: Now, just your problem is how to embed `pagi` into axios url string?

Comment: Yes, I think your problem is that :) so take a look at this example in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation)

Comment: Try this "var url =  `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${pagi}&per_page=20&query=${query}`; "

Answer (score 0):

There are two things

1. Why did you create pagi as an array? From whatever you have mentioned here, I believe pagi should be a number. So instead do

   var pagi = 1;
2. The best way to use pagi and query in url is by doing it like this

   url: `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${pagi}&per_page=20&query=${query}`

As Amit mentioned, you should take a look at template literals.